# How to generate map files for CSS in a sails app?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sails.js

Hi have a sails project with bootstrap included in bower.json:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
...
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0"
...
  }
```

All the css, fonts and js are copied correctly but the map file is not copied to the `assets/vendor/bootstrap` directory nor the `.tmp` dir.

I can't figure out what process copies the filed from `bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css` where the `bootstrap.css.map` file does exists.

There must be something from `tasks/config/bower.js` but I am a bit puzzled on how bower know which files to copy. Especially since the default `layout: 'byType'` does not match the `assets/vendor` at all so there must be something else I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding the following to bower.json:

```
...
"exportsOverride": {
  "bootstrap": {
      "css": ["dist/css/bootstrap.css",
               "dist/css/bootstrap.css.map"],
      "js": "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
      "fonts": "dist/fonts"
  }
}
...
```

This is also a fix to copy fonts. See http://blog.mdarveau.com/2014/10/10/using-fontawesome-and-glyphicons-in-a-sails-app