# FileError: 'responsive-utilities.less' wasn't found, GruntJS not copying all needed files to vendor folder

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less, sails.js, bower

I am new to SailsJS and I have been struggling to understand how to make it work with LESS. My understanding was that it would work out-of-the-box.

```
$ sails --version
0.12.3
```

I am working on **Mac OSX El Capitan**, Here is what I've done.

I have created a new project

```
sails new myProject
```

then willing to integrate **bower** to my setup, I have

```
npm i sails-generate-bower
```

and

```
sails generate bower
```

Installed **Bootstrap** using bower

```
bower install bootstrap --save
```

My `pipeline.js`

```
var cssFilesToInject = [
  'vendor/**/*.css',
  'styles/**/*.css'
];
```

When I `sails lift`, my `layout.ejs` contains:

```
<!--STYLES-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/importer.css">
<!--STYLES END-->
```

that didn't inject my `bootstrap.css` ??

## Trying with LESS

Changed `pipeline.js` to

```
var cssFilesToInject = [
  'styles/importer.less' 
];
```

in my `importer.less` added these lines:

```
@import '../vendor/fontawesome/font-awesome.less';
@import '../vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
```

## My ERROR

```
$ sails lift

info: Starting app...

info: 
info:                .-..-.
info: 
info:    Sails              <|    .-..-.
info:    v0.12.3             |\
info:                       /|.\
info:                      / || \
info:                    ,'  |'  \
info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
info:                 `--'-------' 
info:    __---___--___---___--___---___--___
info:  ____---___--___---___--___---___--___-__
info: 
info: Server lifted in `/Users/joel/Code/sails-website`
info: To see your app, visit http://localhost:1337
info: To shut down Sails, press <CTRL> + C at any time.

debug: -------------------------------------------------------
debug: :: Wed May 25 2016 17:19:32 GMT+0200 (CEST)

debug: Environment : development
debug: Port        : 1337
debug: -------------------------------------------------------
error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
error: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aborted due to warnings.
Running "less:dev" (less) task
>> FileError: 'responsive-utilities.less' wasn't found. Tried - assets/vendor/bootstrap/responsive-utilities.less,assets/styles/responsive-utilities.less,responsive-utilities.less in assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.less on line 56, column 1:
>> 55 @import "utilities.less";
>> 56 @import "responsive-utilities.less";
>> 57
Warning: Error compiling assets/styles/importer.less 
------------------------------------------------------------------------

error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.

error: Troubleshooting tips:
error: 
error:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
error: 
error:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
error: 
error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
error:      e.g., `/Users/joel/Code/sails-website/.tmp` ?
error: 
error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
error:      sudo chown -R 501 /Users/joel/Code/sails-website/.tmp
```

## Running `GruntJS`

```
$ grunt 
Running "bower:install" (bower) task
>> Cleaned target dir /Users/joel/Code/sails-website/assets/vendor
>> Installed bower packages
>> Copied packages to /Users/joel/Code/sails-website/assets/vendor
>> Cleaned bower dir /Users/joel/Code/sails-website/bower_components

Running "clean:dev" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "jst:dev" (jst) task
>> Destination not written because compiled files were empty.

Running "less:dev" (less) task
>> ParseError: Unrecognised input in assets/styles/importer.less on line 20, column 2:
>> 19  @import '../vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
>> 20  # @import '../../vendor/fontawesome/font-awesome.less';
>> 21  # @import '../../vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
Warning: Error compiling assets/styles/importer.less Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

and in verbose mode `grunt --verbose`:

```
...
Running "bower:install" (bower) task
Verifying property bower.install exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: cleanTargetDir, cleanBowerDir, targetDir="./assets/vendor", layout="byType", install, verbose=false, copy, bowerOptions={}
>> Cleaned target dir /Users/joel/Code/sails-website/assets/vendor
bower cached https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.6
bower validate 3.3.6 against https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.3.6
bower cached https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#4.6.3
bower validate 4.6.3 against https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git#~4.6.3
bower cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.4
bower validate 2.2.4 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#1.9.1 - 2
bower install fontawesome#4.6.3
bower install bootstrap#3.3.6
bower install jquery#2.2.4
>> Installed bower packages
Reading /Users/joel/Code/sails-website/bower.json...OK
Parsing /Users/joel/Code/sails-website/bower.json...OK
Reading bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less...OK
Writing assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.less...OK
grunt-bower copying bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less -> assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.less
Reading bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js...OK
Writing assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.js...OK
grunt-bower copying bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js -> assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.js
Reading bower_components/fontawesome/less/font-awesome.less...OK
Writing assets/vendor/fontawesome/font-awesome.less...OK
grunt-bower copying bower_components/fontawesome/less/font-awesome.less -> assets/vendor/fontawesome/font-awesome.less
Reading bower_components/fontawesome/scss/font-awesome.scss...OK
Writing assets/vendor/fontawesome/font-awesome.scss...OK
grunt-bower copying bower_components/fontawesome/scss/font-awesome.scss -> assets/vendor/fontawesome/font-awesome.scss
Reading bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js...OK
Writing assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js...OK
grunt-bower copying bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js -> assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.js
>> Copied packages to /Users/joel/Code/sails-website/assets/vendor
>> Cleaned bower dir /Users/joel/Code/sails-website/bower_components

Running "clean:dev" (clean) task
Verifying property clean.dev exists in config...OK
Files: [no src] -> dev
Options: force=false, no-write=false
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "jst:dev" (jst) task
Verifying property jst.dev exists in config...OK
Files: [no src] -> .tmp/public/jst.js
Options: namespace="JST", templateSettings={}, processContent=undefined, separator="\n\n"
>> Destination not written because compiled files were empty.

Running "less:dev" (less) task
Verifying property less.dev exists in config...OK
Files: assets/styles/importer.less -> .tmp/public/styles/importer.css
Options: banner=""
Reading assets/styles/importer.less...OK
>> ParseError: Unrecognised input in assets/styles/importer.less on line 20, column 2:
>> 19  @import '../vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
>> 20  # @import '../../vendor/fontawesome/font-awesome.less';
>> 21  # @import '../../vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.less';
Warning: Error compiling assets/styles/importer.less Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

## UPDATE

When I try `bower install` alone, I can see that all the necessary files are there, so it looks like my Grunt task is not copying all the needed files

```
bower_components/bootstrap/less$ ls -al
total 576
drwxr-xr-x  46 joel  staff   1.5K May 25 14:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x  16 joel  staff   544B May 27 13:00 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   7.9K May 25 14:12 .csscomb.json
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   456B May 25 14:12 .csslintrc
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   1.5K May 25 14:12 alerts.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   1.2K May 25 14:12 badges.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   1.3K May 25 14:12 bootstrap.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   594B May 25 14:12 breadcrumbs.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   5.5K May 25 14:12 button-groups.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   3.6K May 25 14:12 buttons.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   5.5K May 25 14:12 carousel.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   764B May 25 14:12 close.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   1.4K May 25 14:12 code.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   666B May 25 14:12 component-animations.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   4.8K May 25 14:12 dropdowns.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff    15K May 25 14:12 forms.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff    19K May 25 14:12 glyphicons.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   1.4K May 25 14:12 grid.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   4.2K May 25 14:12 input-groups.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   1.1K May 25 14:12 jumbotron.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   1.1K May 25 14:12 labels.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   3.1K May 25 14:12 list-group.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   900B May 25 14:12 media.less
drwxr-xr-x  32 joel  staff   1.1K May 25 14:12 mixins/
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   1.1K May 25 14:12 mixins.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   3.4K May 25 14:12 modals.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff    14K May 25 14:12 navbar.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   4.8K May 25 14:12 navs.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   7.4K May 25 14:12 normalize.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   861B May 25 14:12 pager.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   2.0K May 25 14:12 pagination.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   6.1K May 25 14:12 panels.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   3.4K May 25 14:12 popovers.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   1.9K May 25 14:12 print.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   1.9K May 25 14:12 progress-bars.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   546B May 25 14:12 responsive-embed.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   4.2K May 25 14:12 responsive-utilities.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   2.9K May 25 14:12 scaffolding.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   4.5K May 25 14:12 tables.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   8.0K May 25 14:12 theme.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   753B May 25 14:12 thumbnails.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   2.9K May 25 14:12 tooltip.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   5.8K May 25 14:12 type.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   747B May 25 14:12 utilities.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff    27K May 25 14:12 variables.less
-rw-r--r--   1 joel  staff   527B May 25 14:12 wells.less
```

### My GruntJS file

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {


    // Load the include-all library in order to require all of our grunt
    // configurations and task registrations dynamically.
    var includeAll;
    try {
        includeAll = require('include-all');
    } catch (e0) {
        try {
            includeAll = require('sails/node_modules/include-all');
        }
        catch(e1) {
            console.error('Could not find `include-all` module.');
            console.error('Skipping grunt tasks...');
            console.error('To fix this, please run:');
            console.error('npm install include-all --save`');
            console.error();

            grunt.registerTask('default', []);
            return;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Loads Grunt configuration modules from the specified
     * relative path. These modules should export a function
     * that, when run, should either load/configure or register
     * a Grunt task.
     */
    function loadTasks(relPath) {
        return includeAll({
            dirname: require('path').resolve(__dirname, relPath),
            filter: /(.+)\.js$/
        }) || {};
    }

    /**
     * Invokes the function from a Grunt configuration module with
     * a single argument - the `grunt` object.
     */
    function invokeConfigFn(tasks) {
        for (var taskName in tasks) {
            if (tasks.hasOwnProperty(taskName)) {
                tasks[taskName](grunt);
            }
        }
    }




    // Load task functions
    var taskConfigurations = loadTasks('./tasks/config'),
        registerDefinitions = loadTasks('./tasks/register');

    // (ensure that a default task exists)
    if (!registerDefinitions.default) {
        registerDefinitions.default = function (grunt) { grunt.registerTask('default', []); };
    }

    // Run task functions to configure Grunt.
    invokeConfigFn(taskConfigurations);
    invokeConfigFn(registerDefinitions);

};
```

### My `tasks/config/bower.js` task

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('bower', {
        install: {
            options: {
                targetDir: './assets/vendor',
                layout: 'byType',
                install: true,
                verbose: true,
                cleanTargetDir: true,
                cleanBowerDir: true,
                bowerOptions: {}
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-task');
};
```

It must be something to fix in here (?)

## Related posts

[This points the problem indeed](https://github.com/smies/sails-generate-bower/issues/1)

I may be able to workaround my issue using Bower `exportsOverride`

```
  "exportsOverride": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "js": "dist/js/*.min.*",
      "css": "dist/css/*.min.*",
      "fonts": "dist/fonts/*.*"
    }
  }
```

[how-to-generate-map-files-for-css-in-a-sails-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477828/how-to-generate-map-files-for-css-in-a-sails-app)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

In pipeline.js you must include the generated CSS file

```
var cssFilesToInject = [
  'styles/importer.css' 
];
```

In `importer.less` you import `boostrap.less` which imports `responsive-utilities.less` and other .less files. But, according to your post, there are no .less file but `bootstrap.less` in `/assets/vendor/bootstrap`.

Did you install bootstrap with `bower install bootstrap --save` ?

**EDIT 2 :**

Here is my tasks/config/bower.js

```
...
grunt.config.set('bower', {
  dev: {
    dest: '.tmp/public',
    js_dest: '.tmp/public/js',
    css_dest: '.tmp/public/styles',
    fonts_dest: '.tmp/public/fonts',
    images_dest: './tmp/public/images/',
    options: {
      expand: true,
      keepExpandedHierarchy: false,
      packageSpecific: {
      'font-awesome': {
        files: [
          "fonts/*"
        ]
      },
      'bootstrap': {
        files: [
          "dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
          "dist/fonts/*"
        ]
      },
      'lodash' : {
        files: [
          'dist/lodash.min.js'
        ]
      },
      'moment' : {
        files: [
          'locale/fr.js',
          'locale/en.js',
          'moment.js',
          'min/moment.min.js'
        ]
      },
....
```

And the tasks/config/less.js to generate .css

...

```
grunt.config.set('less', {
        dev: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/styles/',
                src: ['importer.less'],
                dest: '.tmp/public/styles/',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    });
```

...

You don't have to import .less files. They will be merge into te .css

Comment: where is your vendor directory ?

Comment: see last section **Vendor folder** in the Question. Note that it finds the bootstrap.less, but is complaining about some other files that don't seem to have installed (?)

Comment: yes I did install with `bower install bootstrap --save` see my question. That looks like to be the problem, but how to resolve. Hey thanks for trying to help BTW

Comment: Ok it looks like `grunt` is only copying `bootstrap.less` file. See my the GruntJS verbose output and UPDATE section. Would you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

### Here is what I have done to resolve my problem

## `pipeline.js`

```
var cssFilesToInject = [ 
  'styles/importer.css' 
];
```

## `importer.less`

```
@import '../vendor/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';
```

## `bower.json`

```
  "exportsOverride": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "js": "dist/js/*.min.*",
      "css": "dist/css/*.min.*",
      "less": "less/"    <===== This will copy all the necessary less files
    }
  },
```

## GruntJS task `tasks/config/bower.js`

Changed layout to `byComponent`

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.config.set('bower', {
        install: {
            options: {
                targetDir: './assets/vendor',
                layout: 'byComponent',   <=== was `byType`
                install: true,
                verbose: false,
                cleanTargetDir: true,
                cleanBowerDir: true,
                bowerOptions: {}
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-task');
};
```